# A better word for justice / morality

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a good word to express the concept of "the right thing being done" but avoiding the connotations of the two most obvious words:

- *Justice* - has too much of a connotation of being legalistic or enforced by the police.
- *Morality* - has too much of a connotation of "traditional values" and puritanism.

Is there a better word?

Comment: Didn't fancy any synonyms of 'right'? Fitting, fair, ethical, correct, virtuous, upright...

Comment: Please could you add to your question an example sentence where you would use the word.

Comment: I don't think 'morality' has that connotation, as I think about the word in a philosophical sense rather than a religious sense; however, I suppose it depends on your audience. What context are you using the word in? Likewise with 'justice'. I don't think the phrase "He acted justly" sounds too stuffy or legalistic.

Answer (score 2):

Technically at least, the word in line with *justice* and *morality* that matches 'right' would be ***rectitude***.

However, it depends on where you would like to use the word. That is, the exact import in the context.

Answer (score 2):

Would *decency* work?

[***Decency*** means:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decency) 
a : the quality or state of being decent : propriety b : conformity to standards of taste, propriety, or quality

And [***decent***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decent) is defined as: marked by moral integrity, kindness, and goodwill <*hard-working and decent folks*> <*it's very decent of them to help*>; conforming to standards of propriety, good taste, or morality <*decent behavior*>

One of Merriam-Webster's example sentences for *decency* is:

> *Decency, not fear of punishment, caused them to do the right thing.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend "*conscience*" :

Here's the definition from [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conscience):

> The inner sense of what is right or wrong in one's conduct or motives,
>   impelling one toward right action.
>
> **Ex.** *to follow the dictates of conscience*

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscience?show=0&t=1343744756) also defines conscience as:

> a : the sense or consciousness of the moral goodness or
>   blameworthiness of one's own conduct together with a feeling of
>   obligation to do right or be good
>
> b : a faculty, power, or principle enjoining good acts