# One word that conveys stability, unchanging terms, and word of honor in a local context

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to send a chat to someone that conveys this message/thought but I simply cannot, for the life of me, remember what word I used to use for this.

The message I'm looking to send goes along the lines of, in a positive light,

- I have been able to free up more time recently due to workflow efficiency improvements but for ________ sake I would like to stick to our original terms, which is X days to complete Y milestone.
- Her company gave her a generous Christmas bonus and she can return what she owes you immediately. However, in the name of ________, she wants to follow your original amortization terms.

I was thinking of the word "formality" but in the second example, it may have been a simple, informal oral agreement between the two of them. I'm looking for a word that's sort of the antonym of "indecisiveness" and "turncoat".

**Edit:** I failed to make it clear before. The context is between two/a few parties. The answers and [the flagged question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76478/115608) holds the agreement to widely-accepted societal morals and standards, which may not necessarily be the case for the agreement the parties might have entered into.

What I was looking for, after additional thought, is

> Her company gave her a generous Christmas bonus and she can return
> what she owes you immediately. However, in the name of **[the agreement
> between them, or something that conveys this thought]**, she wants to follow your
> original amortization terms.

This would work for me:

> Her company gave her a generous Christmas bonus and she can return
> what she owes you immediately. However, [in the name of commitment/for the sake of the commitment between the two of you (non-one word)], she wants to follow your
> original amortization terms.

Comment: I'd use 'propriety' if I didn't rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was looking for was **commitment**.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/396662)

Comment: @FeliniusRex Thank you for the instruction. Didn't know that before

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **Integrity**.

"adherence to moral and ethical principles; soundness of moral character; honesty." [integrity](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/integrity?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

**Ethics** seems to work well in the context provided.

[**ethics**  plural in form but singular or plural in construction]

> the discipline dealing with what is good and bad and with moral duty and obligation

[Merriam-Webster]

You could thus say:

> I have been able to free up more time recently due to workflow efficiency improvements but for **ethics'** sake I would like to stick to our original terms, which is X days to complete Y milestone.

Another word that fits the bill nicely is **principle**

> a moral rule or standard of good behavior or fair dealing:

*His guiding principle is that everyone should have equal access to high-quality health care.*

[Cambridge]

You could thus say:

> Her company gave her a generous Christmas bonus and she can return what she owes you immediately. However, in the name of **principle** she wants to follow your original amortization terms.

Answer (score 0):

*For protocol’s sake* refers to adherence to what has been agreed in some official circumstance, such as financial, legal or diplomatic.

Adherence to protocol overrides informal or ad-hoc arrangements such as are implied as possibilities in your two examples.

> Protocol = the system of rules and acceptable behaviour that people or organizations should follow in official situations, for example when they have formal discussions
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/protocol)